# Select Pure Real Roots lying in certain range

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a polynomial equation `f(x)` using `NSolve` and in the equation there is a known parameter `a`. I want to have only the pure real roots lying in the range `0<=x<=1`. These is the code which I have tried

```
x /. NSolve[f[x_] == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1, x, Reals]
```

When I am calculating the value of `x` for parameter `{a1,a2}`, I am getting

```
{{0.950681}, x}
```

Then I found that the possible real roots (without the constraints) are

```
x /. NSolve[f[x_] == 0, x, Reals]

{{-3296.29, -0.0708381, -0.0000599572, 0.950681}, {-3296.29, 1.01867}}
```

This means that when I am taking the parameter `a2` there are no roots that lie between the interval `0<=x<=1`.

Is the constraint `0<=x<=1` which I have written right ?

So if there are no roots then why its showing `x` as the answer ?

Last, if there is no way possible then how to simply select the solutions that lie in the range from the list

```
{{-3296.29, -0.0708381, -0.0000599572, 0.950681}, {-3296.29, 1.01867}}
```

Comment: Your first line gives me a couple of errors. Probably want `f[x]` or `f[x, a]` instead of `f[x_]`, since patterns such as `x_` are used for function definitions and pattern matching, but not in equations.  Also with no definition of `f`, it's hard to say exactly what the problem would be.  Since you're solve for `x`, trying to replace `y` should result in a list of one or more `y`.  Since you're getting a list with a number, we'll need to see the code that generates the output you show.

Comment: Here's an example that fits the code and description presented in the first line of code: `y /. NSolve[(4 x^2 - 1) (9 x^2 - 1) == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1, x]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 I made an error while typing the question. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I hope you understand what I am trying to say.  `x /. NSolve[a+f[x_]== 0 && 0 <= x <= 1, x]` (Letz say `a` is a parameter). If suppose at `a=a1` it has a solution in the range `0 <= x <= 1`, then the command line is OK, but if at `a=a2` say the roots are available but not in the range `0 <= x <= 1`. Then I am getting `{x}` as answer .

Comment: The `_` is meant for pattern matching and definitions, so you really shouldn't be putting it in your `NSolve[]` expression. Try `NSolve[a + f[x] == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1, x]`.